# Postfix and Amazon SES - how to automatically throttle when receiving 454 errors back from SES?

Tags: postfix, amazon-ses

Will Postfix automatically queue and resend mail if the initial attempt to send results in a ["454 Throttling failure: Maximum sending rate exceeded"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/reach-sending-limits.html) response from the Amazon SES SMTP server?

The postfix server is configured to send mail through Amazon SES, as per the Amazon's instructions for [Integrating Amazon SES with Postfix](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/postfix.html).

I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282065/postfix-handling-amazon-ses-maximum-send-rate-error but it's unanswered and only suggests using what seems to be an unrelated properly to rate limit all mail to a certain domain. Is this the best option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `default_destination_concurrency` setting is probably the simplest thing, though you could create a custom transport and make sure all of your messages to the relay server go through that.. something similar to this, possibly:

http://blog.pheonixsolutions.com/configure-thrttling-for-outgoing-mails-in-postfix/

except use a single regex to direct all mail through your custom transport.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will retry sending the messages after a throttling error. In my experience I found that postfix retried sending the messages about 5 minutes after the original throttling error was reported in the log file.